# How to customize the UserInterface of Jitsi Meet implemented using API in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, jitsi-meet

I want to customize the user interface of Jitsi Meet. I want to remove the "Invite others" option located at the center bottom. How can I do that in Android Studio using java?

[image]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_details);

    try {
        JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                .setServerURL(new URL(""))
                .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                .setConfigOverride("requireDisplayName", true)
                .setConfigOverride("reqiureInviteOthers", false)
                .build();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public void onClickMeet(View v) {
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.meetId);
    String text = editText.getText().toString();

    if (text.length() > 0) {
        JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder().setRoom(text).build();
        JitsiMeetActivity.launch(this, options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder builder = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder();
builder.setFeatureFlag("invite.enabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                .setServerURL(new URL(""))
                .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                .setConfigOverride("requireDisplayName", true)
                .setConfigOverride("reqiureInviteOthers", false)
                .setFeatureFlag("invite.enabled", false)// <-- add this line
                .setFeatureFlag("add-people.enabled", false)// <-- add this line
                .build();
```

this is [the list](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/mobile-feature-flags) of available feature flags that you can turn on or off Jitsi Features